# Is there a topology with respect to which a poset is connected iff its topologically connected?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

A poset $P$ is said to be *connected* iff for all $x,y \in P$ we can 'zigzag' from $x$ to $y$ in finitely many steps. That is, iff for all $x,y \in P$ there exists a finite sequence $a : n \rightarrow P$ such that $$x \leq a_0 \geq a_1 \leq \cdots a_{n-2} \geq a_{n-1} \leq y$$ or $$x \leq a_0 \geq a_1 \leq \cdots a_{n-2} \leq a_{n-1} \geq y$$ (depending on whether $n$ is even or odd).

Is there a natural way of endowing a poset $P$ with a topology such that $P$ is connected in the sense defined above iff its topologically connected? (I am not trying to suggest that there's only one way of doing this.)

Comment: somewhat related, and also somewhat not (but hopefully you find it interesting) is the theory of finite topological spaces http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf

Comment: If you take the topological realization of a poset, then it is connected iff the poset is connected. (The topological realization is a simplicial complex with vertex set equal to the poset and simplex $[v_0,\ldots,v_n]$ for every chain of comparable elements $v_0<v_1<\cdots<v_n$.)

Answer (score 1):

Lets denote the equivalence relation 'zigzagging' by ~. It partitions the set $P$ into classes $(P_i)$. Taking all possible unions of those classes defines a topology that is connected iff it only contains the empty set and $P$.

This works for any equivalence relation.

Comment: You let the equivalence classes be a basis for the open sets. Could you call that the characteristic topology for that equivalence relation, much like you have the characteristic function for a given subset?

Comment: @Arthur: I don't know if this topology has a name but I don't think it's an interesting topology. If it was I would probably call it 'topology associated to the poset'.

Comment: This is the same as letting the connected components in the poset sense be a basis for a topology.